# Unresolved reference to an object

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a huge view with a bunch of tables and columns selected.

I need to join on another database which is on the same server, but SQL Server is giving me a message that the reference to the database object is unresolved.

`myView contains an unresolved reference to object db2.dbo.table`

```
USE db1
CREATE VIEW dbo.myView as
    SELECT * FROM dbo.table as main

    INNER JOIN db2.dbo.table as otherTable
    ON (
        db1NotMain.value = otherTable.value

        -- same happens when I do the following
        dbo.table2 = otherTable.value

    )
    INNER JOIN dbo.table2 as db1NotMain
    ON (
        db1NotMain.value = someOtherTableElsewhereInDb1.value
    )
```

I'm really stumped here, because it's not making any sense.

The error happens on the `otherTable` inner join, and only there when I add this.

**EDIT 2021:** This happened because of a typo.

Comment: Which object? Please include the actual and complete error message.

Comment: Could you include the missing ON's "get stuff" SQL?

Comment: You can't use an alias until you define it.  At the time you use b1NotMain.value  db1NotMain is not defined.   Same for someOtherTableElsewhereInDb1.  Why do you have a join to dbo.table as main with no on referencing main?  Forget the view.  First get the query to run.

Comment: The view itself is a work in progress, it's working fine, and has a bunch of other joins. However, when I add the one join for a database outside my view database the problem arises.

Comment: What part of you cannot use an alias until it is defined is not clear? Same database or different database does not matter.

Comment: It doesn't matter to Visual Studio if I put it before or after the alias is instantiated. The object (db2) is just not recognized.

Comment: Visual Studio?  What does Visual Studio have to do with this?  Really, all this, and the core problem is select * from db2.dbo.table fails?  You need to work on problem solving and problems statements.

Comment: So, the issue is with `db2.dbo.table`. Does the `db2` database exist? Is it accessible? Does it have `dbo.table`? Is that table accessible too?

Answer (score 0):

Order of joins matters here. You're trying to use `db1NotMain` before you've introduced it in your query. Switch the order of the joins:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    dbo.table AS main
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.table2 AS db1NotMain
    ON
    -- get stuff (please include the rest of your ON clause)
INNER JOIN 
    db2.dbo.table AS otherTable
    ON
    db1NotMain.value = otherTable.value
```

Comment: the reason I didn't include the rest from that on clause, is that the unresolved reference ONLY happens within the otherTable on clause.

Comment: I believe you, but I don't know if my answer is 100% valid because as I mentioned, the order of JOINs will matter (you can't reference a table before you've introduced it). I wanted to check your entire query. SSMS sometimes complains about the wrong thing.

Comment: I didn't know it would matter, thanks though! I've revised my question a tiny tad, the same error happens if I explicitly (without using what I defined in my as on db1NotMain) call the object on dbo.table2.

Comment: I see your edit. You have two constraints in your first ON clause but none in your second still. Can we see the entire query as you ran it to get the error?

Comment: I can't really insert my entire view here, as it contains 166 lines of sql (simple stuff). I just need to get a reference working, it's giving me the error in VS2013 IDE

Comment: I'm probably not good enough at giving information about my problem, but the thing is that it's somehow not recognizing db2 as an object. How can this happen in the first place? It works when I try to do an isolated `SELECT` outside of my view definition.

Comment: @NichlasTorgersen: It's tough to diagnose without a minimal example that reproduces the issue. All I can see at the moment is that you're trying to use `db1NotMain` alias before you've defined that alias with `JOIN dbo.table2 AS db1Notmain`. If your real query follows that pattern, that will be the issue.

Comment: I understand, but would the fact that it's a view contained in DB1 cause the problem?

Comment: @NichlasTorgersen: No, it shouldn't. If it was a permissions problem you would be seeing a different message.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that on fly directly. You have two options:

1. Create a linked server in DB invironment, then create a SP to take care of it.
2. Get two DataSets for them, then merge two datatables into one based on usersID.

Hope it gives you some idea.

Comment: It's definitely possible in SQL server.

Comment: You don't need a linked server to query a database on the same Sql Server instance.

Answer (score 0):

The comments about using an alias before it is defined are correct. That is one problem.
The line `dbo.table2 = otherTable.value` does not make sense because dbo.table2 is a table not a column. That is another problem.

If you are working in Visual Studio, presumeably SSDT, then the primary error is an IDE error. SSDT attempts to 'compile' your sql code using the tsql engine. An SSDT project, like any VS project, needs all databases referenced to be defined so that it can resolve your  sql code.

You've probably not defined a connection or reference to `db2`. To do this, you can right-click on the References node of the SSDT project and select `Add Database Reference`. Or you can import a .dacpac of db2 to accomplish the same.

If you have imported from an existing database into your project, I believe there is an option to suppress errors from unresolved references.

However, I would strongly suggest you first create your view using SSMS and get it working, because you have a couple of syntax errors that are more critical than the VS SSDT error.